# Unable to connect Kafka using SASL_SSL & SCRAM-SHA-512 from Databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, databricks

I've been unable to consume messages from Kafka when connecting from Databricks using authentication method requiring SASL_SSL & SCRAM-SHA-512.

I've tried following code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("KafkaStreaming") \
    .master("local[*]") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "moped.srvs.cloudkafka.com:9094") \
    .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL") \
    .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "SCRAM-SHA-512") \
    .option("kafka.sasl.username", "abc") \
    .option("kafka.sasl.password", "abc") \
    .option("startingoffsets", "earliest") \
    .option("subscribe", "abc-default") \
    .load()

query = df.writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("console") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

Could anyone please suggest what could be the possible reason? Or can anyone can share any sample working code involving SASL_SSL and SCRAM-SHA-512 authentication.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: It doesn't give any error but rather the stream writer keeps running the command without returning any messages consumed from Kafka.

Comment: Try display(df) - console output isn’t visible

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't give you an error, then it's connected correctly.   In your case the problem is that `console` output isn't shown in the notebook - it will be shown in the drivers/executors logs. And because you didn't specify the trigger, the call `awaitTermination` isn't terminated.

If you want to see the content of the streaming dataframe, you need to use the [`display` function](https://www.databricks.com/spark/getting-started-with-apache-spark/dataframes#view-the-dataframe):

```
display(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I've tried this & it stays in following state & doesn't return

"Stream initializing..."

Comment: Here's the updated code:

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Kafka Example").getOrCreate()

# Read the data from the Kafka topic
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "moped.srvs.cloudkafka.com:9094")\
    .option("subscribe", "abc")\
    .option("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")\
    .option("sasl.mechanism", "SCRAM-SHA-512")\
    .option("sasl.username", "abc")\
    .option("sasl.password", "abc")\
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")\
    .load()

display(df)